# I have Error: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 while using new ReactQueryStreamedHydration

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13, react-query, tanstackreact-query

I am trying to create Next.js 13 app using App folder and ReactQuery.
Based on [this example](https://tanstack.com/query/v5/docs/react/examples/react/nextjs-suspense-streaming) I've setup my project. Everything works fine, data is pre-loaded on server, I get fallback from Suspense while data is loading and data is displayed when they are fetched.
When I reload (F5) page, I get this nextjs error

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Call Stack
updateDehydratedSuspenseComponent
node_modules/.pnpm/next@13.4.19_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (16348:0)
updateSuspenseComponent
node_modules/.pnpm/next@13.4.19_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (16048:0)
beginWork$1
node_modules/.pnpm/next@13.4.19_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (17361:0)
beginWork
node_modules/.pnpm/next@13.4.19_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (25675:0)
performUnitOfWork
node_modules/.pnpm/next@13.4.19_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (24526:0)
workLoopSync
node_modules/.pnpm/next@13.4.19_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (24242:0)
renderRootSync
node_modules/.pnpm/next@13.4.19_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (24197:0)
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot
node_modules/.pnpm/next@13.4.19_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (23339:0)
workLoop
node_modules/.pnpm/next@13.4.19_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js (261:0)
flushWork
node_modules/.pnpm/next@13.4.19_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js (230:0)
MessagePort.performWorkUntilDeadline
node_modules/.pnpm/next@13.4.19_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js (534:0)
```

I am not sure if this is something on my side, or problem is in experimental react query package.

This is how I am using  it:

providers:

```
'use client'

import { ReactNode, useState } from 'react'
import { SessionProvider } from 'next-auth/react'
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from '@tanstack/react-query'
import { ReactQueryStreamedHydration } from '@tanstack/react-query-next-experimental'

type ProvidersProps = {
    children?: ReactNode
}

export const Providers = ({ children }: ProvidersProps) => {
    const [queryClient] = useState(
        () =>
            new QueryClient({
                defaultOptions: {
                    queries: {
                        staleTime: 5 * 1000
                    }
                }
            })
    )

    return (
        <SessionProvider>
            <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
                <ReactQueryStreamedHydration>{children}</ReactQueryStreamedHydration>
            </QueryClientProvider>
        </SessionProvider>
    )
}
```

app/finance/bank/page.tsx

```
import { Header } from '@/components/server/header'

import { BankAccountModal } from './components/bank-account-modal'
import { BankAccountList } from './components/bank-account-list'
import { Suspense } from 'react'
import { BankAccountSkeleton } from './components/bank-account-skeleton'

const Bank = async () => {
    return (
        <>
            <div className="flex justify-between items-center">
                <Header heading="Bank accounts" />
                <BankAccountModal />
            </div>
            <section className="grid gap-4 lg:grid-cols-2">
                <Suspense fallback={<BankAccountSkeleton />}>
                    <BankAccountList />
                </Suspense>
            </section>
        </>
    )
}

export default Bank
```

BankAccountList.tsx

```
'use client'

import { Card, CardContent, CardHeader, CardTitle } from '@/components/ui/card'
import { useBankAccounts } from '@/lib/queries/server/finance'

export const BankAccountList = () => {
    const { data } = useBankAccounts()

    return (
        <>
            {data.bankAccounts.map((account) => (
                <Card key={account.id} className="cursor-pointer hover:bg-muted">
                    <CardHeader>
                        <CardTitle>{account.name}</CardTitle>
                    </CardHeader>
                    <CardContent>
                        <div className="flex justify-between items-center">
                            <p className="font-semibold tracking-tight">IBAN</p>
                            <p>{account.iban ? account.iban : '-'}</p>
                        </div>
                        <div className="flex justify-between items-center">
                            <p className="font-semibold tracking-tight">Balance</p>
                            <p>{account.balance}</p>
                        </div>
                    </CardContent>
                </Card>
            ))}
        </>
    )
}
```

api/finance/bank-accounts/route.ts

```
export const GET = async (req: Request) => {
    const session = await getUserSession()

    if (!session) {
        return NextResponse.redirect(new URL(Route.index, req.url))
    }

    const bankAccounts = await prisma.bankAccount.findMany({
        where: {
            userId: session.user.id
        }
    })

    if (!bankAccounts) {
        return NextResponse.json(
            { error: "Couldn't fetch bank accounts." },
            { status: 500 }
        )
    }

    return NextResponse.json({ bankAccounts }, { status: 200 })
}
```

When I console.log data, it appears as valid JSON, also this error only shows up when I reload page manually.

I already tried reinstalling node_modules, debug responses (only found valid JSON).

I expect no errors when reloading page manually.

Comment: can you show a codesandbox reproduction?